# Android list view under tabs

Tags: android

I m developing one application and in my class i have 4 tabs and inside each tab i have list view. i want to display data into the list view. i m providing the data in the array but the problem is when my app starts it display the data of 4 tabs under single tab. bt when i click one by one on tabs den it shows the data correctly.

Here is the source code..:

```
public class test extends TabActivity  implements OnTabChangeListener 
{
private static final String LIST_TAB_TAG = "News";
private static final String LIST_TAB_TAG2 = "List2";
private static final String LIST_TAB_TAG3 = "List3";
private static final String LIST_TAB_TAG4 = "List4";
private TabHost tabHost,tabHost1,tabHost2,tabHost3;
private ListView listView,listview2,listview3,listview4;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.clistview);

    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    // setup must be called if you are not inflating the tabhost from XML
    tabHost.setup();
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listview2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
    listview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list3);
    listview4 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list4);

    // create some dummy coordinates to add to the list
List<String> list1Strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        list1Strings.add("");
        list1Strings.add("Item 2");
        list1Strings.add("Item 3");
        list1Strings.add("Item 4");
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1Strings));



    List<GeoPoint> pointsList2 = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    pointsList2.add(new GeoPoint((int)(464464645), (int)(979646664)));
    pointsList2.add(new GeoPoint((int)(7976566), (int)(987464313)));
    listview2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pointsList2));

    List<GeoPoint> pointsList3 = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    pointsList3.add(new GeoPoint((int)(32.864*1E6), (int)(-117.2353*1E6)));
    pointsList3.add(new GeoPoint((int)(37.441*1E6), (int)(-122.1419*1E6)));
    listview3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pointsList3));

    List<GeoPoint> pointsList4 = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    pointsList4.add(new GeoPoint((int)(464464645), (int)(979646664)));
    pointsList4.add(new GeoPoint((int)(7976566), (int)(987464313)));
    listview4.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pointsList4));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST_TAB_TAG).setIndicator("News", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.newsicon)).setContent(new TabContentFactory() 
    {
        public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
            return listView;
        }
    }));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST_TAB_TAG2).setIndicator("Opinion", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.opinionicon)).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
            return listview2;
        }
    }));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST_TAB_TAG3).setIndicator("Press", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pressicon)).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
            return listview3;
        }
    }));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST_TAB_TAG4).setIndicator("My Stocks", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mystockicon)).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
            return listview4;
        }
    }));



    //HACK to get the list view to show up first,
    //tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    //tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}

@Override
/*protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}*/


public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a chance you can add your layout XML file?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you extend TabActivity but also extract the tabhost and call setup()?  Usually, you call setup only if it's not a TabActivity.  It looks like you got this code from my blog on Map Activities.  I also have a tutorial on List activities that might be easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I apologise Josh it seems I have cut and pasted the wrong xml file, I have been messing around with implenting different types of layout with maps tabs and listviews this is why you tutorial is in the same workspace, which is a little like my desk.......VERY Messy

This is the correct xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget30"
```

android:layout_width="320px"
android:layout_height="58px"
android:src="@drawable/grasshe"
>

```
</LinearLayout>
```